# Необязательные столбцы в моделях ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть четыре модели: Hoodie, Longsleeve, Shirt, Cart. 
Первые три модели содержат одинаковые свойства - Id, материал, размер и т.д. 
Последняя содержит Id, Quantity, Guid. 
Изначально решил попробовать на лонгсливах, добавил эти свойства:

```
public Longsleeve Longsleeve { get; set; }
public int LongsleeveId { get; set; }
```

Но мне все-таки надо в корзину класть не только лонгсливы, а еще худи и футболки. Как сделать, чтобы столбцы (лонгслив, худи или футболки) были необязательными, то есть я мог бы отправить запрос на добавление чего-то одного, а не сразу три параметра передавать? По логике он как-то должен допускать Null, но я не совсем понимаю, как это сделать. Очевидно, просто сделать Nullable не поможет, потому что будет ошибка. Как лучше поступить и есть ли возможность что-то сделать не перелопачивая все модели?

Comment: А если вы через некоторое время начнёте продавать так же кроссовки, мячи, велосипеды и попугайчиков? Вы будете вносить изменения в проект и пересобирать его и заново публиковать?

Comment: Для первых трех моделей используй одну модель Product с категорией, куда и записывай Hoodie, Longsleeve, Shirt

Comment: Это первый мой "проект", я делаю его как раз чтобы понять, как это все работает. Поэтому мне и нужен совет, как лучше сделать модели.

Comment: @HelloWorld не очень понимаю, как это — одна модель вместо тех трёх, просто с ещё одним столбцом категории? или просто модель, в которой будут свойства типа Longsleeve longsleeve снова?

Comment: @TimofeyMelentev почитайте про viewModel и model и чем они отличаются, тогда станет понятнее как может быть 1 модель вместо трех. Как сказал товарищ выше, вам нужно абстрагироваться от конкретных изделий. И создать отдельно модель для продуктов, где будут храниться абсолютно любые изделия,  а для вывода (лонгсливов, шортов и попугаев), вы будете использовать viewModel.